# Hiding source in a particle system

Tags: particles

Does anyone knows how to hide the emitting source of particles but show the particles only. I am using hair Type emitter, and particles are emmited from the vertex as reference location. I don't want to use the particle instance modifier because of the memory usage

Answer (score 1):

Just unclick the checkbox in the sub menu "Render" located inside the particle System.